# NoMethodError in UsersController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting the following error in my app when I visit a user profile page not signed into the app (I'm using Devise):

NoMethodError in UsersController#show
undefined method `connections' for nil:NilClass

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:19:in `show'

When I'm logged in the error goes away. I know why it's failing. I just need help coming up with the proper solution.

The error occurs on this line in my users controller:

```
def show
@connection = current_user.connections.build(user_id: current_user, otheruser_id: @user)
end
```

A connection form appears for users logged into the app (simply put, a button appears that asks if you would like to connect with this person as a friend). However, I'm checking if the user is logged in on the user view "show" page with `<% if user_signed_in? %>` before the form.

Here's the relevant code from the view:

```
 <%= render 'connect_form' if user_signed_in? %>
```

connect_form

```
<% unless current_user == @user %>
  <% if @contact.present? && user_signed_in? %>
      <%= @user.first_name %> is your  <%= @contact.description %> (<%= link_to "edit contact", edit_connection_path(:id => @contact.id, :user => @user) %>)<br \>
  <% else %>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>How do you know <%= @user.first_name %>? (<%= link_to "edit contact", new_connection_path(:user => @user) %> )
  <% else %> 
<% end %><br \>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

connection_form (creating a new one)

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
How do you know <%= @user.first_name %>?
  <%= form_for(@connection) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :description, Connection::CONNECTIONTYPE, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
  <%= f.hidden_field(:otheruser_id, :value => @user.id) %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary btn-small" %>
  <% else %>
<% end %>
```

Why is my app trying to load a nil array `@connections even when I have the check user_signed_in? Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: can you put in the contents of the users controller as well

Comment: Hello and thanks for the reply. The first code sample with `@connection` is where the error occurs. I added the show action from the users controller to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would do is put a check to only build the connection if the current user exist.

```
def show
  @connection = current_user.connections.build(user_id: current_user, otheruser_id: @user) if current_user
end
```

The main thing to notice is the: `if current_user` at the end of the line

Comment: Good idea but unfortunately it didn't change anything :( . I tried adding if user_signed_in? and still nothing. Any other ideas?

Comment: NEVERMIND IT WORKED! Thank you so much! What happened was after I added if current_user, I had a similar instance variable and the error fired on that one (the error line number changed). I added if current_user to the end of that variable as well and everything worked. Thank you so much again

Answer (score 0):

From the error message

`` undefined method `connections' for nil:NilClass ``

`current_user` is nil, a quickly test for this is

`def show
@connection = User.new.connections.build(user_id: current_user, otheruser_id: mock_user_id)
end`

For your case, maybe you didn't store the login user somewhere